# My data in my grid does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have an observable collection in my view model (using WPF c#).

I 'attach' this to my datagrid

I have a button

I press the button and it will search for a particular row and update the value of a view.

the data in the grid is not updated.

i thought by using an observable it WOULD update?

View Model:

```
private Visibility _JobHistorySelected;

public ObservableCollection<InformedWorkerModel.JobProfile> JobHistory
{
    get { return _JobHistory; }
    set
    {
        _JobHistory = value; RaisePropertyChanged("JobHistory");
    }
}
```

relevant xaml:

```
<DataGrid      Name="dgJobHistory"     
        ItemsSource="{Binding  ActiveRecord.JobHistory}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        SelectionMode="Single"
        AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"                           
        GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" 
        CanUserAddRows="False" 
      Visibility="{Binding ActiveRecord.JobHistoryIsSelected}" 
      Grid.Row="1"
         IsReadOnly="True"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
      MouseDoubleClick="dgJobHistory_MouseDoubleClick"                     
      >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Id" Binding="{Binding JobId, StringFormat='0000000000'}" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </mui:DataGridTextColumn>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Booked" Binding="{Binding DateBookedFormated}" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </mui:DataGridTextColumn>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Status" Binding="{Binding JobStatus}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </mui:DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

code behind:

```
public void SaveNewStatus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as ApplicationViewModel;
    InformedWorkerBusinessService.JobStatus.SaveStatus(vm.ActiveRecord.JobRecord.JobStatus, vm.ActiveRecord.JobRecord.JobRef);
    foreach (var history in vm.ActiveRecord.JobHistory)
    {
        if (history.JobRef== vm.ActiveRecord.JobRecord.JobRef)
        {
            history.JobStatus = vm.ActiveRecord.JobRecord.JobStatus;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE

When I check in the code-behind whether the row is found and field is updated it is..

thanks

Comment: try to set the modified object back to DataGrid, `dgJobHistory.DataSource = vm;`

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Hi, thanks this sort of did work. I had to minimise my form and maximise it to see the change. I did try ad use myGrid.UpdateLayout but it made no difference

Comment: If you want a super cheat way (since you are already using code-behind), you can unset the view's `DataContext` to null, and set it back to the VM. This forces the View to update all bindings.

Comment: @Jai hi, thanks yes. That would have worked but I found remove and insert back in is less 'heavy' but thanks for the option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` just means that the collection has implementations to notify when records are *added* or *removed* from the collection. If a property of a record changes, *that* record's property must contain the means to notify the UI of it's changes. You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the items in the collection for example.

Comment: HI, now you said it makes sense. I could remove from collection and re-add it I guess.  thanks

Comment: That is one way to do it. Better solution is to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your InformedWorkerModel.JobProfile class

Comment: @lokusking yes, that is probably the better way - thanks :)